# Strange exception with Java8 Nashorn regex engine

Tags: regex, java-8, nashorn

I ran into a strange `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 64` error while parsing text using Nashorn Javascript engine. To reproduce the problem in JJS:

```
var col0 = " xxxx,         xxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx, xxxx xxxxx xxxxx ";
var name = /([^\s]+),(.*)+/.exec(col0);
```

Some other variants of the test string also cause the same exception, for example.

```
var col0 = "x,         xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx, xxxx xxxxx xxxxx ";
```

Happens with JDK8 versions 25, 31 and 40ea (on Windows 8).

Comment: Do you have a stack trace, and if so, can you edit it into your question?

Comment: `(.*)+` is a very strange expression anyway…

Comment: Yes, the regex is indeed "funny" (result of editing) which is probably why this was not caught in JDK tests. Changing the regex to be more sensible "fixes" the error, too, so I'm good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in our regexp implementation. I've filed a bug for it:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8073818

Update: You can use the `-Dnashorn.regexp.impl=jdk` option as a workaround. This makes Nashorn use the java.util.regex package instead of Joni which doesn't show this bug.

Comment: Is there a reason for nashorn having its own regex engine, or in other words, what are the impacts of switching nashorn to using the `java.util.regex` package?

Comment: JavaScript regex is not fully compatible with Java regex (for example Unicode support is rather poor). Frankly, I'd rather use JDK regex in internal scripting as default anyway.

Comment: Is this really working? I'm using Java/Nashorn 9, but a test regexp with Unicode categories is not matching correctly, even though I verified that it does work with Pattern+Matcher...